# issue with incrementing integer elements in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, while-loop

Consider the list:
`mylist = [1,2,3,'a','b',4,5,'c',6]`

What I want to do is make a program that returns the list after incrementing each integer element by `1`, skipping through the non-integer elements. I tried the following code to define a function using the *while loop* with parameter `x`:

```
def f(x):
    i = -1
    while (i < (len(x) - 1)):
        i+=1
        if (type(x[i]) != "<class 'int'>"):
            continue
        x[i]+=1
    return x
```

Now, I try to use this function to return the value of `f(mylist)`. Following is the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]
```

As you can see, it returns the input itself, which was very unexpected when I actually wanted that to be

```
[2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7]
```

Even after looking at my code numerous times, I couldn't find what's wrong with it.

Will be pleased if someone figures it out for me.

Comment: `"<class 'int'>"` is a string. Is any element in your list literally equal to this string? Presumably not. You're looking for [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: `"<class 'int'>"` is a string. The type of an object cannot possibly equal _this exact string_. See the documentation about `type`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#type

Comment: please, do not use UPPERCASE in questions titles

Comment: my advice will be to separate integers from strings and work with different homogeneous lists instead of having one heterogeneous list

Comment: @AzatIbrakov ya sure.. but that doesn't tell me the issue in this method

Comment: Please don't edit out the error in your code now that you understand it. That makes it impossible to understand what the answers are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
def f(x):
    return [i + 1 if type(i) is int else i for i in x]
```

or by for loop

```
def f(x):
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if type(v) is int:
            x[i] += 1
    return x
```

and correcting the function that in the description

```
def f(x):
    i = -1
    while i < len(x) - 1:
        i+=1
        if type(x[i]) != int:
            continue
        x[i]+=1
    return x

mylist = [1,2,3,'a','b',4,5,'c',6]
print(f(mylist))
```

This function will return you a new list that increases each int value by one and for the other values, it will keep them as is.
The function will return

```
[2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but could you tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The line `if (type(x[i]) != "<class 'int'>"):` need to be `if (type(x[i]) != int):`

Comment: since classes are unique we can use `is`/`is not` to compare them instead of `==`/`!=`

Comment: @Vector The code that I edited base on your code returning me the same result  `[2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7]`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check if a item of type `int` before incrementing, otherwise leave as is.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]
>>> [x + 1 if isinstance(x, int) else x for x in lst]
[2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7]
```

Also if you want a normal loop approach instead of a list comprehension, a `for` loop is more suitable, since you know how how many elements you need iterate. A `while` loop is only suitable if you don't know the number of iterations you'll need. It's also easier to create a new list here, instead of dealing with indices.

```
def f(x):
    result = []
    for item in x:
        if isinstance(item, int):
            result.append(item + 1)
            continue
        result.append(item)
    return result

print(f([1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]))
# 2, 3, 4, 'a', 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
i = -1
while (i < (len(x) - 1)):
    i+=1
    if (not isinstance(x[i], int)):
        continue
    x[i]+=1
return x
```

Comment: Consider writing a few lines! This adds a lot of value to your "answer".

Comment: and fixing the indentation

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code to get the desired output as stated in your question .

```
def f(x):
i = 0
while (i < (len(x))):
    if (type(x[i])) == int:
        x[i]+=1         
    else:
        print("Char",x[i])
    i+=1
return x
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 4, 5, 'c', 6]
f(mylist)
```

Output:
[image]